# Show whether or not it would be appropriate to do a Poisson approximation for a binomial distribution with $p = 0.07$ and $n = 120$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

**QUESTION:** Show whether or not it would be appropriate to do a Poisson approximation for a binomial distribution with $p = 0.07$ and $n = 120$

**MY WORKING:**

I know that whenever $p$ is small enough (which is in this case) and $n$ is large enough (which is also $n=120$). We approximate the binomial distribution through poisson. However I don't know how to show it rigorously here. Can anyone guide me how do I approach it?

Comment: You can write the pmf of the binomial distribution as

$P(X=x)=\frac{n}{n-\lambda}\cdot \frac{n-1}{n-\lambda}\cdot \ldots \cdot \cdot \frac{n-x+1}{n-\lambda}\cdot \frac{\lambda ^x}{x!}\cdot \left(1-\frac{\lambda}{n}\right)^n$ Then you can compare it with the poisson distribution.

Comment: @callculus42 still comparing doesn't result in anything. I have to plug in the given values to check. I have tried to compare, but it doesn't result any fruitful. It only gives $\lambda=\frac{\lambda}{n}$ which gives $n=1$. Nothing of importance.

Comment: Can't you just calculate the (relative) difference of the binomial distribution and the poisson distribution from x=0 to x=120 and the see if it is appropriate?

Comment: It relates to goodness of fit by tests like the chi square test, etc, but I haven't studied Statistics. You could see this for a start. https://vortarus.com/assessing-distribution-fit/