# What is the probability that for $10$ randomly selected orders that $3$ would be for the blue shoes, $2$ for the red shoes, $1$ for the black shoes.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

**STATEMENT:** A certain style of shoes made by a company comes in blue, red, black, and white. From experience, the company knows the blue shoes are the most popular with $33$% of the sales. This is followed by the red and black shoes respectively with sales of $26\%$ and $25\%$ for this style of shoes.

**QUESTION:** What is the probability that for $10$ randomly selected orders that $3$ would be for the blue shoes, $2$ for the red shoes, $1$ for the black shoes, and the remaining orders for the white shoes.

**MY WORKING:**

We are given that the probability for success of blue shoes to be sold is $0.33$, that for red is $0.26$ and for black is $0.25$

If we were to choose and find probability of any two classes of all three (blue,red and blue), it was hypergeometric that I will have used. Here the thing is entire different, there are total 3 classes and I am required to find the probability of $10$ randomly selected orders will have $3$ blue shoes, $2$ red shoes, and $1$ black shoes, and the remaining orders for the white shoes. I am unable to figure out which distribution or method should I use here to solve it.

Can any one guide me. That will be really appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You are confused with percentages, i.e. $33\%=0.33$. Are the numbers 25 and 26 percentages?

Comment: Have you learnt the multinomial distribution ?

Comment: Three independent conditions must be true at the same time: 3 out of 10 are blue, 2 out of 7 non-blue ones are red, and 1 out of 5 black or white ones are black. Multiply the three solutions to the simpler problems.

Comment: @trueblueanilue no I haven't. I just saw it, and I think I can do this myself from here. Thank you for guidance.

Comment: @callculus42 I am not confused, I have been working whole day so I guess that's why I made this silly mistake. Thanks for pointing it out. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @trueblueanil I used the multinomial distribution with $n=10$, $n_1=3$, $n_2=2$, $n_3=1$, $P_1=0.33$, $P_2=0.26$, $P_3=0.26$ & have arrived at $P(n_1=3, n_2=2, n_3=1)=\frac{10!}{3!\times2!\times1!}(0.33)^3(0.26)^2(0.25)$. Now when I solve this I get the result $181.44$ which is impossible. Can you guide me what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have left out the probability and numbers of white shoes

Comment: @trueblueanil thanks. I am making alot of silly mistakes. I think I must take a break now. I have been working like hours :D

Comment: @trueblueanil If u have minute, will you look at this problem. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4492032/show-whether-or-not-it-would-be-appropriate-to-do-a-poisson-approximation-for-a?noredirect=1#comment9423390_4492032